# When I click on link in my gmail message it should open an activity on my phone

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-activity

Is their a way to format a link in a gmail, which when opened in a browser or a app, when clicked opens a different activity on a phone?

I mean let's say in an email you send a link and link has some formatting like YouTube and this when clicked opens the YouTube app on the android phone.

Comment: Your sentence structure makes my brain bleed.  Please consider rewording your question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are trying to do is to get the browser to emit an intent to start another software component. This is not possible. 
What happens with the Youtube link is that you are asking the browser to handle a certain mime type, which it does by calling an external application. There are a few mime types that in Android will bring up external applications, but that is completely different to having the browser emitting an intent in order to start executing a specific component.

If you manage to get this to work, you have discovered a serious security flaw in Android.

Comment: Extending this concept further... could you register an application as a mime-type handler with your own mime-type, then have the link go to a regular site which emits that mime-type?

Comment: Interesting use case. I will give it a go. I can't foresee any problems, although I have never done it on Android. You will still have to convince the users to download and install your mime type handler app.

Comment: So this is possible if the user accepts to install the mime type handler app?